# create array object with elements BufferedReader and BufferedWriter

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a return object that contains a BufferReader and a BufferWriter.  Here are my two classes:

test.java

```
package FileIO;

import java.io.*;

public  class Test{ 
    static String line = null;
    public static void Main() {
        String fileName = Input.getInput();

        Object[] ioObject = new Object[2];
        ioObject = OpenFile.openFileName(fileName,"READ");      

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = ioObject[0];  

        do{
           //line = null; 
           line =  ReadLine.getLine(bufferedReader); 
           System.out.println(line);
        } while (line != null);
   }    
}
```

OpenFile.java

```
package FileIO;

import java.io.*;

public class OpenFile {
    static Object[] ioObject = new Object[2];
    static BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    static BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;

   public static Object[] openFileName(String fileName, String type){


       if(type == "READ"){ 


         try{ 
            // FileReader reads text files 
            FileReader fileReader =  new FileReader(fileName);

            // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
            bufferedReader =  new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            ioObject[0] = bufferedReader;
            System.out.println("you lucky dog, file " + fileName + " was found"); 

         }catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("FATAL ERROR: File " + fileName + " not found"); 
            System.out.println(ex);
         } 
      }else if(type == "WRITE"){       

      }else{
         System.out.println("FATAL ERROR: type input can only be READ or WRITE");        
         System.exit(0);
      } 
      return ioObject;
   }
}
```

I'm getting an error on this line in test.java:

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = ioObject[0];
```

incompatible types object can not be converted to BufferedReader.  I'm confused as ioObject[0] is a BufferedReader.

Comment: `if(type == "READ")` will not work.  `if (type.equals("READ"))` instead

Comment: that wasn't the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ioObject` is an `Object[]`, so the compiler can only determine that `ioObject[0]` is an `Object` (even though *you* know you put a `BufferedReader` in there.

You need to either cast it to a `BufferedReader`:

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = (BufferedReader) ioObject[0];
```

Or, instead of using an `Object[]`, create a strongly-typed class to hold the two references.

```
class IoObject {
  BufferedReader reader;
  BufferedWriter writer;

  // Constructor, etc.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Object is the superclass type. Once you convert the BufferedReader to an Object, you cannot convert it back without a cast.

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = (BufferedReader) ioObject[0];
```

Also, you will need to catch `ClassCastException`